# FindRoot or NSolve with Bounded interval

Tags: equation-solving

It's possible to implement some bounded interval using **Findroot** ?

I'm trying to solve this kind of equation:

```
EFO = e[0.150/hbarc, 0.300/hbarc]
troot[\[Eta]_] := 
 FindRoot[e[Tc[\[Tau], 0, 0, \[Eta]], Mc[\[Tau], 0, 0, \[Eta]]] - 
    EFO == 0, {\[Tau], tmin}]
tfo[\[Eta]_] := troot[\[Eta]][[1, 2]]
```

That gave me the solution, however the findroot try to solve on each possible Eta, can I give some **boundary** like, solve this equation between emin and emax ?

I tried to do it using NSolve, however Tc and Mc are interpolation variables coming from another code, so I guess I can't use it ?

e is a previous equation set analytically previously. I can put here the equation if needed:

```
dn0dTfull[T_] = g T^2 (m/T)^2 (3 BesselK[2,m/T] + m/T BesselK[1, m/T]);
e0full[T_] = T^2 dn0dTfull[T]; 
e[T_, \[Mu]_] = 4 Cosh[\[Mu]/T] e0full[T];
```

Here to experiment, I give tables of Tc and Mc:

```
    In[328]:= Table[
     Tc[t, 0, 0, \[Eta]], {t, tmin, tmax}, {\[Eta], emin, emax}]
    
    Out[328]= {{0.182292, 0.269708, 0.383436, 0.523777, 0.687455, 
      0.866924, 1.05039, 1.2228, 1.3677, 1.4698, 1.51759, 1.50549, 
      1.43494, 1.31408, 1.15622, 0.977434, 0.793908, 0.619567, 0.464566, 
      0.334698, 0.231697}, {0.0716525, 0.107187, 0.156508, 0.229516, 
      0.343474, 0.516587, 0.732682, 0.883657, 0.986054, 1.05251, 1.08255, 
      1.075, 1.0302, 0.949548, 0.831047, 0.649025, 0.43933, 0.291726, 
      0.196482, 0.134692, 0.0915409}, {0.0507062, 0.0757684, 0.111338, 
      0.165161, 0.250609, 0.381221, 0.56341, 0.755404, 0.868255, 0.931962,
       0.959483, 0.952628, 0.911084, 0.830745, 0.686618, 0.484546, 
      0.322895, 0.211689, 0.140663, 0.0955352, 0.0646638}, {0.0406486, 
      0.0606893, 0.0895268, 0.133691, 0.204502, 0.31325, 0.465137, 
      0.649319, 0.788629, 0.857957, 0.885968, 0.879072, 0.836034, 
      0.743793, 0.574322, 0.399305, 0.264661, 0.172186, 0.113522, 
      0.0766878, 0.0517963}, {0.0345122, 0.0515018, 0.0761779, 0.11427, 
      0.175759, 0.270539, 0.403, 0.566266, 0.719236, 0.800501, 0.830989, 
      0.823599, 0.775686, 0.665203, 0.498455, 0.345599, 0.228166, 
      0.147658, 0.0968363, 0.0651772, 0.043962}, {0.0302976, 0.0451988, 
      0.0669884, 0.10082, 0.155703, 0.240553, 0.359234, 0.50569, 0.654801,
       0.749498, 0.784292, 0.775988, 0.720338, 0.598097, 0.444744, 
      0.307807, 0.2026, 0.130594, 0.0853113, 0.0572655, 
      0.038588}, {0.0271878, 0.040552, 0.060195, 0.0908293, 0.14072, 
      0.21804, 0.326283, 0.459855, 0.598938, 0.70093, 0.741145, 0.731583, 
      0.667739, 0.544766, 0.404261, 0.279378, 0.183439, 0.117876, 
      0.0767692, 0.0514238, 0.0346258}, {0.0247795, 0.0369557, 0.0549257, 
      0.0830509, 0.129, 0.200356, 0.300337, 0.423706, 0.55287, 0.654777, 
      0.699501, 0.688678, 0.61995, 0.50225, 0.372359, 0.25701, 0.168411, 
      0.107946, 0.0701297, 0.046897, 0.0315589}, {0.0228483, 0.0340731, 
      0.0506942, 0.0767849, 0.119522, 0.186006, 0.279234, 0.394272, 
      0.514893, 0.612891, 0.659489, 0.647906, 0.578578, 0.467541, 
      0.346394, 0.23883, 0.156232, 0.0999284, 0.0647887, 0.0432647, 
      0.0291003}, {0.0212582, 0.0317005, 0.0472057, 0.0716055, 0.111661, 
      0.174069, 0.261646, 0.369716, 0.483089, 0.576205, 0.622387, 0.61068,
       0.543284, 0.438556, 0.324739, 0.223688, 0.146112, 0.093288, 
      0.0603791, 0.0402723, 0.0270763}, {0.0199216, 0.0297065, 0.04427, 
      0.0672368, 0.105012, 0.163946, 0.246704, 0.348834, 0.456001, 
      0.544392, 0.589068, 0.577625, 0.513025, 0.413894, 0.30633, 0.210831,
       0.137537, 0.0876774, 0.0566636, 0.0377556, 0.0253751}}

In[329]:= Table[
 Mc[t, 0, 0, \[Eta]], {t, tmin, tmax}, {\[Eta], emin, emax}]

Out[329]= {{1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 
  1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 
  1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 
  1.52032}, {4.19032, 4.14321, 4.07089, 3.90298, 3.54315, 2.90001, 
  2.08765, 1.73248, 1.59702, 1.53413, 1.51001, 1.51586, 1.55363, 
  1.63881, 1.83013, 2.38222, 3.19601, 3.71638, 3.98759, 4.10636, 
  4.16302}, {4.6514, 4.61521, 4.55293, 4.4148, 4.12769, 3.62201, 
  2.85479, 2.06429, 1.7461, 1.62553, 1.583, 1.59314, 1.66132, 1.83529,
   2.3274, 3.1931, 3.85424, 4.26516, 4.48371, 4.58298, 
  4.63135}, {4.86377, 4.83399, 4.77925, 4.66, 4.4148, 3.98492, 
  3.33344, 2.50136, 1.93724, 1.73663, 1.67175, 1.68695, 1.79358, 
  2.09935, 2.84226, 3.62126, 4.18217, 4.532, 4.71927, 4.80544, 
  4.84737}, {4.99029, 4.96462, 4.91548, 4.80944, 4.59256, 4.21295, 
  3.63835, 2.88702, 2.18107, 1.8699, 1.77523, 1.79703, 1.95623, 
  2.42261, 3.20363, 3.8921, 4.38709, 4.69615, 4.86205, 4.93887, 
  4.97608}, {5.07579, 5.05301, 5.0082, 4.91205, 4.716, 4.37302, 
  3.85404, 3.17439, 2.45686, 2.03096, 1.89696, 1.92748, 2.1545, 
  2.73013, 3.46155, 4.08317, 4.53036, 4.8096, 4.9597, 5.02946, 
  5.0631}, {5.13815, 5.11753, 5.07617, 4.98778, 4.80788, 4.49318, 
  4.01694, 3.39337, 2.71474, 2.21975, 2.04045, 2.08161, 2.37713, 
  2.98167, 3.65689, 4.22718, 4.63755, 4.89376, 5.03156, 5.09574, 
  5.12658}, {5.18601, 5.16707, 5.12856, 5.04645, 4.87955, 4.58754, 
  4.14552, 3.56686, 2.93259, 2.42194, 2.20472, 2.25626, 2.59588, 
  3.18408, 3.8114, 4.34066, 4.72152, 4.95922, 5.08709, 5.14675, 
  5.17532}, {5.22411, 5.20654, 5.17041, 5.09353, 4.93738, 4.66411, 
  4.25031, 3.70863, 3.11382, 2.61621, 2.38005, 2.43832, 2.79125, 
  3.35016, 3.93753, 4.43299, 4.78951, 5.01191, 5.13156, 5.18745, 
  5.21413}, {5.2553, 5.23885, 5.20476, 5.13231, 4.98524, 4.72779, 
  4.33779, 3.82726, 3.26633, 2.79057, 2.55194, 2.6124, 2.96001, 
  3.48935, 4.04299, 4.50998, 4.84595, 5.05544, 5.16814, 5.22082, 
  5.24592}, {5.28138, 5.2659, 5.23356, 5.16493, 5.02567, 4.7818, 
  4.41221, 3.92839, 3.39669, 2.94339, 2.71048, 2.77029, 3.10559, 
  3.60815, 4.13283, 4.5754, 4.89374, 5.09214, 5.19887, 5.24878, 
  5.27251}}
```

Here the values of some settings

```
tmin = 0.25;
tmax = 10.25;
emin = -10.3;
emax = 10.3;
hbarc = 0.197326938; 
GeV = 1/hbarc;
m = 1.116 GeV;
g = 1/(2 Pi^2);
```

Thank you for the answers

Comment: Without the definitions for `Tc` and `Mc` there is no way for us to experiment. Also if you are looking to work on a bounded interval for `η`, please specify the interval of interest.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added the tables because I can't give directly the interpolated functions

Comment: Also, what are the values for `m` and `g`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Revised for addition of `GeV = 1/hbarc`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dn0dTfull[T_] = g T^2 (m/T)^2 (3 BesselK[2, m/T] + m/T BesselK[1, m/T]);
e0full[T_] = T^2 dn0dTfull[T];
e[T_, μ_] = 4 Cosh[μ/T] e0full[T];

EFO = e[(15/100)/hbarc, (3/10)/hbarc] // Simplify;

tmin = 0.25;
tmax = 10.25;
emin = -10.3;
emax = 9.7;(* Your Table only goes to 9.7 rather than 10.3 *)

hbarc = 0.197326938;
GeV = 1/hbarc;
m = 1.116 GeV;
g = 1/(2 Pi^2);
```

Your tabular data:

```
dataTc = {{0.182292, 0.269708, 0.383436, 0.523777, 0.687455, 0.866924, 
    1.05039, 1.2228, 1.3677, 1.4698, 1.51759, 1.50549, 1.43494, 1.31408, 
    1.15622, 0.977434, 0.793908, 0.619567, 0.464566, 0.334698, 
    0.231697}, {0.0716525, 0.107187, 0.156508, 0.229516, 0.343474, 0.516587, 
    0.732682, 0.883657, 0.986054, 1.05251, 1.08255, 1.075, 1.0302, 0.949548, 
    0.831047, 0.649025, 0.43933, 0.291726, 0.196482, 0.134692, 
    0.0915409}, {0.0507062, 0.0757684, 0.111338, 0.165161, 0.250609, 0.381221,
     0.56341, 0.755404, 0.868255, 0.931962, 0.959483, 0.952628, 0.911084, 
    0.830745, 0.686618, 0.484546, 0.322895, 0.211689, 0.140663, 0.0955352, 
    0.0646638}, {0.0406486, 0.0606893, 0.0895268, 0.133691, 0.204502, 0.31325,
     0.465137, 0.649319, 0.788629, 0.857957, 0.885968, 0.879072, 0.836034, 
    0.743793, 0.574322, 0.399305, 0.264661, 0.172186, 0.113522, 0.0766878, 
    0.0517963}, {0.0345122, 0.0515018, 0.0761779, 0.11427, 0.175759, 0.270539,
     0.403, 0.566266, 0.719236, 0.800501, 0.830989, 0.823599, 0.775686, 
    0.665203, 0.498455, 0.345599, 0.228166, 0.147658, 0.0968363, 0.0651772, 
    0.043962}, {0.0302976, 0.0451988, 0.0669884, 0.10082, 0.155703, 0.240553, 
    0.359234, 0.50569, 0.654801, 0.749498, 0.784292, 0.775988, 0.720338, 
    0.598097, 0.444744, 0.307807, 0.2026, 0.130594, 0.0853113, 0.0572655, 
    0.038588}, {0.0271878, 0.040552, 0.060195, 0.0908293, 0.14072, 0.21804, 
    0.326283, 0.459855, 0.598938, 0.70093, 0.741145, 0.731583, 0.667739, 
    0.544766, 0.404261, 0.279378, 0.183439, 0.117876, 0.0767692, 0.0514238, 
    0.0346258}, {0.0247795, 0.0369557, 0.0549257, 0.0830509, 0.129, 0.200356, 
    0.300337, 0.423706, 0.55287, 0.654777, 0.699501, 0.688678, 0.61995, 
    0.50225, 0.372359, 0.25701, 0.168411, 0.107946, 0.0701297, 0.046897, 
    0.0315589}, {0.0228483, 0.0340731, 0.0506942, 0.0767849, 0.119522, 
    0.186006, 0.279234, 0.394272, 0.514893, 0.612891, 0.659489, 0.647906, 
    0.578578, 0.467541, 0.346394, 0.23883, 0.156232, 0.0999284, 0.0647887, 
    0.0432647, 0.0291003}, {0.0212582, 0.0317005, 0.0472057, 0.0716055, 
    0.111661, 0.174069, 0.261646, 0.369716, 0.483089, 0.576205, 0.622387, 
    0.61068, 0.543284, 0.438556, 0.324739, 0.223688, 0.146112, 0.093288, 
    0.0603791, 0.0402723, 0.0270763}, {0.0199216, 0.0297065, 0.04427, 
    0.0672368, 0.105012, 0.163946, 0.246704, 0.348834, 0.456001, 0.544392, 
    0.589068, 0.577625, 0.513025, 0.413894, 0.30633, 0.210831, 0.137537, 
    0.0876774, 0.0566636, 0.0377556, 0.0253751}};
```

To recreate the [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) from your `Table` values

```
tc = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Flatten[
      Table[{t, η}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {η, emin, emax}], 1], 
     dataTc // Flatten}]];

Tc[t_, 0, 0, η_] := tc[t, η];
```

Verifying,

```
Table[Tc[t, 0, 0, η], {t, tmin, tmax}, {η, emin, emax}] == dataTc

(* True *)
```

Similarly, for your other `Table`

```
dataMc = {{1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 
    1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 
    1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032, 1.52032}, {4.19032, 4.14321, 
    4.07089, 3.90298, 3.54315, 2.90001, 2.08765, 1.73248, 1.59702, 1.53413, 
    1.51001, 1.51586, 1.55363, 1.63881, 1.83013, 2.38222, 3.19601, 3.71638, 
    3.98759, 4.10636, 4.16302}, {4.6514, 4.61521, 4.55293, 4.4148, 4.12769, 
    3.62201, 2.85479, 2.06429, 1.7461, 1.62553, 1.583, 1.59314, 1.66132, 
    1.83529, 2.3274, 3.1931, 3.85424, 4.26516, 4.48371, 4.58298, 
    4.63135}, {4.86377, 4.83399, 4.77925, 4.66, 4.4148, 3.98492, 3.33344, 
    2.50136, 1.93724, 1.73663, 1.67175, 1.68695, 1.79358, 2.09935, 2.84226, 
    3.62126, 4.18217, 4.532, 4.71927, 4.80544, 4.84737}, {4.99029, 4.96462, 
    4.91548, 4.80944, 4.59256, 4.21295, 3.63835, 2.88702, 2.18107, 1.8699, 
    1.77523, 1.79703, 1.95623, 2.42261, 3.20363, 3.8921, 4.38709, 4.69615, 
    4.86205, 4.93887, 4.97608}, {5.07579, 5.05301, 5.0082, 4.91205, 4.716, 
    4.37302, 3.85404, 3.17439, 2.45686, 2.03096, 1.89696, 1.92748, 2.1545, 
    2.73013, 3.46155, 4.08317, 4.53036, 4.8096, 4.9597, 5.02946, 
    5.0631}, {5.13815, 5.11753, 5.07617, 4.98778, 4.80788, 4.49318, 4.01694, 
    3.39337, 2.71474, 2.21975, 2.04045, 2.08161, 2.37713, 2.98167, 3.65689, 
    4.22718, 4.63755, 4.89376, 5.03156, 5.09574, 5.12658}, {5.18601, 5.16707, 
    5.12856, 5.04645, 4.87955, 4.58754, 4.14552, 3.56686, 2.93259, 2.42194, 
    2.20472, 2.25626, 2.59588, 3.18408, 3.8114, 4.34066, 4.72152, 4.95922, 
    5.08709, 5.14675, 5.17532}, {5.22411, 5.20654, 5.17041, 5.09353, 4.93738, 
    4.66411, 4.25031, 3.70863, 3.11382, 2.61621, 2.38005, 2.43832, 2.79125, 
    3.35016, 3.93753, 4.43299, 4.78951, 5.01191, 5.13156, 5.18745, 
    5.21413}, {5.2553, 5.23885, 5.20476, 5.13231, 4.98524, 4.72779, 4.33779, 
    3.82726, 3.26633, 2.79057, 2.55194, 2.6124, 2.96001, 3.48935, 4.04299, 
    4.50998, 4.84595, 5.05544, 5.16814, 5.22082, 5.24592}, {5.28138, 5.2659, 
    5.23356, 5.16493, 5.02567, 4.7818, 4.41221, 3.92839, 3.39669, 2.94339, 
    2.71048, 2.77029, 3.10559, 3.60815, 4.13283, 4.5754, 4.89374, 5.09214, 
    5.19887, 5.24878, 5.27251}};
```

Recreating the `InterpolatingFunction`

```
mc = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Flatten[
      Table[{t, η}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {η, emin, emax}], 1], 
     dataMc // Flatten}]];

Mc[t_, 0, 0, η_] := mc[t, η];
```

Verifying,

```
Table[Mc[t, 0, 0, η], {t, tmin, tmax}, {η, emin, emax}] == dataMc

(* True *)
```

Plotting,

```
f[τ_?NumericQ, η_?NumericQ] := 
 e[Tc[τ, 0, 0, η], Mc[τ, 0, 0, η]] - EFO

ContourPlot[f[τ, η] == 0,
 {τ, tmin, tmax}, {η, emin, emax},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {τ, η}),
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[f[τ, η], {τ, tmin, tmax}, {η, emin, emax},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {τ, η}),
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 2,
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &),
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick},
 ViewPoint -> Above]
```

[image]

```
troot[η_?NumericQ] := 
 Check[τ /. 
   FindRoot[f[τ, η] == 0, {τ, tmin, tmin, tmax}], $Failed]

Plot[troot[η], {η, emin, emax},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
     {η, τ})] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: firstly, thank you for the answer, in this `troot[η_?NumericQ] := 
 Check[τ /. 
   FindRoot[f[τ, η] == 0, {τ, tmin, tmin, tmax}], $Failed]`  as I understand, you have the bounded interval for t, but there is an implicit interval for eta ?

Comment: There is nothing implicit about `eta`, it is the explicit numeric argument to `troot`. The `eta` range iterator in the various plotting functions define its range.

Comment: Okay, consequently he calculate each time the Findroot for this particular point of eta in the function ? Great, it's perfectly what I needed, thank you !